# UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios9, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view and for some cells I want to return a specific height, and some others, I want to fall back to automatic size. Here is my code:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(something){
        return UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize;
    }else{
        return some CGSize
    }
}
```

However, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try to return `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`. I've also tried to set the size to automatic dimension on flow layout itself:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout* layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionViewLayout;
layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize;
```

I'm also getting the same error when I assign to `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize` either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related to your problem, but I also had a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with a collection view with a flow layout. Turns out changing the `.estimatedItemSize` fixed the issue :

```
let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

// this breaks
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

// this does not break
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
```

My cells have just a label, so they are smaller than 100x100. I guess it is not good if you give an estimated size that is larger than the actual size...

Hope this helps anyone.